# how to run amplify codegen in where codegen is already configured?

Tags: aws-amplify, graphql-codegen

we have a project repo where backend team have added new apis.
other developers have run and configured amplify and codegen.
now I want to add these new  queries and their types.
when I run amplify codegen i get this error:

```
Please download the schema.graphql or schema.json and place in C:\leag\nevClon\newwebsite before adding codegen when not in an amplify project
```

and when i run amplify add codegen it says Codegen support only one GraphQL API per project.
could someone guide me whats the right way to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this problem in the past. Things I've tried include ...

1. Make sure you are in the correct amplify environment.
2. Run amplify pull to ensure you are up to date.
3. Try re-initializing using `amplify init`
4. When all else fails, try re-cloning the repository.

Answer (score 2):

it's showing that because you still have graphqlconfig.yml file in your src folder, look for the graphqlconfig.yml file and delete it then try again, hopefully it's work this time.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have to delete the file graphqlconfig.yml in the root of my project
[image]
[image]

Then I ran the command again, it was enough to recreate the file properly:

```html
amplify codegen
```

Ref: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2166#issuecomment-450940562

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was in wrong backend environment after changing the environment problem was fixed.